# SSH2 what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I'm having trouble copying a file from my laravel project to another server. This is what I'm doing.

```
    $connection = ssh2_connect($this->ftpHostname, $this->ftpPort);

    if (!$connection) {
        throw new \Exception("Couldn't connect to {$this->ftpHostname}:{$this->ftpPort}");
    }

    $loginResult = ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'usrname', 'pswrd');

    if (!$loginResult) {
        throw new \Exception("Username or Password not accepted for {$this->ftpHostname}:{$this->ftpPort}");
    }

    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
    $fullFilePath = storage_path() .'/'.$this->argument('local-file');
    $remoteFilePath = "ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/{$this->argument('remote-folder')}/SomeFolder/{$this->argument('remote-filename')}.txt";

    $copyResult = copy($fullFilePath, $remoteFilePath);
```

But it's giving me this error

```
[ErrorException]
copy(): Unable to open ssh2.sftp://Resource id #621/My Folders/Upload only/sample.txt on remote host
```

I'm really new in ssh how do I solve this?

Comment: i'm using ssh2 that's all I know @ThomasMoors

Comment: is it normal that it returns this?
ssh2.sftp://Resource id #621
because im confused where the error is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast $sftp to an int before using it in the ssh2.sftp:// fopen wrapper.

```
$remoteFilePath = "ssh2.sftp://" . (int)$sftp . "/{$this->argument('remote-folder')}/SomeFolder/{$this->argument('remote-filename')}.txt";
```

From [ssh2_sftp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php)

> The example code above fails unless you cast the $stftp to (int) or use intval()
>
> $stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r'); // Fails
>
> $stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://" . (int)$sftp . "/path/to/file", 'r'); // joy

Since [copy()](http://php.net/copy) will be using the fopen wrappers to interpret your ssh2.sftp:// uri, that should help.

Comment: Hi, it's still the same
copy(): Unable to open ssh2.sftp://621/My Folder/Upload only/sample
  .txt on remote host

Comment: My bad, it was the folder structure creating the error. Your answer is correct!